# Delay ajax OnBegin until fadeOut of DOM - MVC5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fade out a div containing html from a partial view when a user clicks on a link and fade in the newly fetched partial view. The problem I am having is that sometimes my view is fetched before the fadeout of the original partial view is finished so I end up seeing the partial views switch out, fade out, then fade back in again. Is there a way to delay the ajax request until the fade out is complete?

Here is the order of operations I am trying to achieve.
User clicks link > partial view A fades out > new partial view is fetched via ajax > partial view B fades in.

This is what is happening at times

User clicks link > partial view A begins to fade out but partial view B comes in before it finishes fading > partial view B fades out > partial view B fades back in again.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Me", "ManageUserAccount", null, new AjaxOptions
                                   {
                                       HttpMethod = "GET",
                                       UpdateTargetId = "ajax-update",
                                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                       OnBegin = "ajaxBegin",
                                       OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess"
                                   }, new { @class = "active" })    


 @Ajax.ActionLink("Alerts", "ManageAlerts", null, new AjaxOptions
                               {
                                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                                   UpdateTargetId = "ajax-update",
                                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                   OnBegin = "ajaxBegin",
                                   OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess"
                               }, new { @class = "active" })



<div id="ajax-update">
            @Html.Action("ManageUserAccount")
        </div>  


<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxSuccess() {
        $('#ajax-update').fadeIn();
        //sometimes the new partial view is returned before this even finishes its job
    }
    function ajaxBegin() {
        $('#ajax-update').fadeOut();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i make a very similar function... but i use get, done and effect. and works! I use to make a complex website without postback, change partial is in the menu for simulate the change page

```
$(".menu-button").click(function (e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
    var urlID = document.URL.split('#')[1];
    if (id != urlID) {
        location.hash = id;
        changepartial(id);
    }
 });

    function changepartial(id)
    {
         var path = "../home/"+id;
         getOut();
         $.get(path).done(function (result) { 
  //done is for wait get result after make the next step.

            $("#Contenant").html(result);
            getIn();
         });
    }

    function getOut() {
        $("#Contenant").effect('drop', { direction: 'left' }, 100);
    }

    function getIn() {
        $("#Contenant").effect('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Pablote. This doesn't look like its MVC. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Let me update my title.

Comment: yes i'm use mvc5 and jquery, well this code is all in javascript path is the addres to your partial view ex: "../shared/_news"

Comment: I forget in controler I use this structure    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Fan()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return PartialView("_Fan");
        }

Comment: okay I see now. And where does changePartial get called from? I'm hoping to try and get a solution that works with the Ajax helpers. Do you hook this up to a button of some sort, cancel the request, fade out, then resend the request using jquery?